# CSS - Apply styles to absolute elements child when we do mouse hover the paren

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply styles to elements that are absolutely positioned within a  label on an unordered list, the idea is that by passing the mouse over the main parent elements can apply custom styles to all elements children who have an absolute position.

In the example we can see that when mouse over the main element, the styles applied correctly for items that do not have the absolute position, but the , is not affected, and it is this element that I need to change blue too.

**Here example:** http://jsfiddle.net/milindex/en8oaLct/

```css
ul.menu {
    margin: 40px 0 0 0;
    padding:0;
}
ul.menu li{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

ul.menu li a {
    margin: 3px 0;
    padding:10px 20px;
    list-style:none;
    display: block;
    background: #FBFBFB;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size:13px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#202020;
    
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
    background: #EEE;
    color: blue
}

ul.menu li a > i {
    position: absolute;
    right:20px;
    top:13px;
    color:#7AB900;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            Item 1
            <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            Item 2
            <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            Item 3
            <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current styles have a color for the `i` element, you just need to style that one in the case the parent is hovered, like so:

```
ul.menu li a:hover > i {
    color: blue;
}
```

```css
ul.menu {
    margin: 40px 0 0 0;
    padding:0;
}
ul.menu li{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

ul.menu li a {
    margin: 3px 0;
    padding:10px 20px;
    list-style:none;
    display: block;
    background: #FBFBFB;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size:13px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#202020;
    
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
    background: #EEE;
    color: blue
}

ul.menu li a > i {
    position: absolute;
    right:20px;
    top:13px;
    color:#7AB900;
}

ul.menu li a:hover > i {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            Item 1
            <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            Item 2
            <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            Item 3
            <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul.menu {
    margin: 40px 0 0 0;
    padding:0;
}
ul.menu li{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

ul.menu li a {
    margin: 3px 0;
    padding:10px 20px;
    list-style:none;
    display: block;
    background: #FBFBFB;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size:13px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#202020;
    
}

ul.menu li a:hover,
ul.menu li a:hover i {
    background: #EEE;
    color: blue
}

ul.menu li a > i {
    position: absolute;
    right:20px;
    top:13px;
    color:#7AB900;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            Item 1
            <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            Item 2
            <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            Item 3
            <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The rule you were missing was this one

```
ul.menu li a:hover i
```

Absolute positioning was not the problem in your case.